# What is the difference between the Trinitarian concept of God and the Mormon concept of God?

Tags: nature-of-god, lds, trinity

Just curious. Hope I can get helpful feed back.

Comment: Can you narrow down your focus? You could be asking about the essence of God, or you could be asking about the characteristics of God.

Comment: Can you explain to me both, essence an characteristics?

Comment: I'd rather flag it as "too broad".

Answer (score 3):

In Wikipedia page, [Christian Denomination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_denomination), we see Mormonism as a Nontrinitarian Denomination. Explaining that:

> Mormons see themselves as believing in a Godhead comprising the
>   Father, Son, and Holy Ghost as separate personages united in purpose.

On a separate page, [God in Mormonism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_in_Mormonism), explains that The Father in the Godhead is the same Jewish God, [Elohim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elohim) that we know.

Basically, unlike the [trinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity), most Mormons believe that:

> the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost are not said to be one in
>   substance or essence; instead, they remain three separate beings, or
>   personages, completely united in will and purpose as one God

Comment: This should explain the Trinity, too, to be a complete answer.

Comment: @CecilBeckum why are you under the impression that it is necessary to upvote a question to answer it? Perhaps the answerer didn't think the question merited an upvote yet still could provide an answer.